# Convergence of geometric mean over arithmetic mean $G_n / A_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Fix $a,d\in \mathbb{R}$ an consider the arithmetic sequence $x_n = a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,...$ ($x_n = a + (n-1)d $ for each $n$). Now consider
$$ A_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \quad \text{ and }\quad G_n = \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}$$
I want to compute the limit of $X_n = G_n / A_n$. Note that  for the case $a=d=1$, $G_n = \sqrt[n]{n!}$ and $A_n = (n+1)/2$. Using Stirling formula, it yields $\lim X_n = 2e^{-1}$. My work for the general case:

(1) Clearly, by geometric-arithmetic mean inequality, $X_n \leq 1$.

(2) Using the formula for the sum of the terms of an arithmetic sequence, $A_n = \frac{2a+(n-1)d}{2}$

(3) Using a convenient property of Gamma function, $x_1\cdot x_2 \cdots x_n = d^n \frac{\Gamma (a/d + n)}{\Gamma (a/d)} \Rightarrow G_n = d \left(\frac{\Gamma (a/d + n)}{\Gamma (a/d)} \right)^{1/n}$

(4) Lastly, I compute $G_n / A_n$ and I applied $\Gamma (n + a/d) \sim \Gamma (n) n^{a/d}$ as $n\to \infty$. But I got stucked. After some computations, it seems that the limit is infinity... but we know this is impossible since we found a case with finite limit $(a=d=1)$ or, even worse, we know $X_n$ is bounded!. **Can anyone help me solving this general case?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a typo. It should be a $d$. Thanks. I have edited the post.

Comment: Just use Stirling's on $\Gamma(a/d+n)$ and you will get the same $2/e$.